# Is this a chinese mandarin song and what is the title?

Tags: mandarin, songs

Is this a mandarin Chinese song? And can you tell what is the title?
https://youtu.be/ctVtOHrxMNg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's mandarin, song name "致你"(means "to you"), singer name "yihuik苡慧"